# Mysql - How to create column that automatically sums rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have a mysql database table called "character" with columns like name, strength, intelligence, skill. I want to create a column that sums up strength, intelligence and skill AUTOMATICALLY. Is this possible?

I have seen loads of pages showing how to do queries. I did a query just fine, such as
select (str+intel+skl) as sum from character;
It returns a sum just fine.

But what I'm missing (don't understand) is how to:

1. either AUTOMATE that query into my mysql db (for example, when I do "select * from character", it will show "strength, intelligence, skill, sum"),
2. OR where/how to incorporate the mysql query into my rails app so that SUM shows up in real time, and when edits to, for e.g. strength occur, the SUM is updated accordingly.

A key point, I am summing columns across a row (strength, intelligence, skill), not summing a column (strengths of several characters).

Comment: I think you should search for triggers and it should run on insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, if I'm understanding your question correctly and the strength, intelligence, skill columns are numeric data types.

```
select strength, intelligence, skill, strength+intelligence+skill as sum
from character
```

As suggested, a view could then be created pretty easily with:

```
create view totals as
select strength, intelligence, skill, strength+intelligence+skill as sum
from character
```

Comment: Great, this created a new table called "totals" with the desired values. Do I then merge the new table "totals" with "character"?

Comment: Actually, you'll just want to add the other appropriate columns to it, such as character_id...  The view can contain anything you need.

Answer (score 3):

Your best option is to use a trigger (or the similar code at the app level).

Using a view works too, but if you need it frequently you'll want it pre-calculated for performance reasons.

For an introduction to triggers, see:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/triggers.html

You probably want something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER character_sum_ins BEFORE INSERT ON character
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.sum = NEW.strength + NEW.intelligence + NEW.skill;

CREATE TRIGGER character_sum_upd BEFORE UPDATE ON character
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.sum = NEW.strength + NEW.intelligence + NEW.skill;
```

Alternatively, pre-calculate the sum in your app and store it accordingly.

Side note: ask yourself if you really need this stored though. As point out by another commenter, there might be no need for the auto-calculated data at all.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to make this into a stored procedure. The procedure could do the calculations, and you could read the results as though they were columns.

You could also probably get away with a simple view for this use case.

Comment: Looked up stored procedures, great. After I create a stored procedure, how do I call it in my view?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this in mysql, just add the values up when displaying them, seriously.

Or if you really want, sum them in mysql in your SELECT statement when returning them.

Don't use a trigger just to maintain a total of some numbers - they are a seriously screwy way of confusing all future develoeprs on the project.

Comment: Can you give me an example of "adding values when displaying them"?

Comment: You can get the server to add them up, by using a calculated column in your select (SELECT a+b+c AS total_stats FROM tbl ... ) OR you add them up in your client code. Doing more work in client code is considered superior for scalable applications, because it's easier to scale clients than servers.

Comment: @MarkR, What if the table is pretty large i.e. 10M rows. You wouldn't do it client side (imagine looping through all those rows), you would run out of RAM.