# How to insert row into MySQL table with SUM of certain values

Tags: mysql, sum

I have a table that looks like so

```
ACCOUNT AMOUNT
Income  59
Income  69
Income  99
Income  45
COGS    43
COGS    34
COGS    45
Expense 44
Expense 55
```

I want to insert a row into this table that will have the ACCOUNT value=`Gross Profit` and the AMOUNT Value = SUM(Income and COGS)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843969/insert-new-row-with-data-computed-from-other-rows. Also check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006636/mysql-how-to-create-column-that-automatically-sums-rows

Answer (score 2):

Use an [**`INSERT ... SELECT Syntax`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html)

**Query**

```
INSERT INTO tblName(ACCOUNT, AMOUNT) 
SELECT 'Gross Profit',
SUM(AMOUNT)
FROM tblName
WHERE ACCOUNT IN ('Income', 'COGS');
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6768b/1)